# Get a part of a string using regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to get `//table[@data-account='test']` from the string `//table[@data-account='test']//span[contains(.,'FB')]` using regex.

I am new to regex and not able to use the existing samples for my purpose. 
Thanks

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) is a very good read on the topic, and should get you up to speed on regular expressions quite quickly. And it's definitely valuable knowledge you are certainly going to reuse. Regardless of that: one input-output pair is hardly enough for us to judge which part of your input are fixed and which are variable, to even justify the use of regular expressions here.

Comment: it can be done without regular expression , is it your only option ? are you interested in other ways too ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for that. You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) method like;

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this string
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified string array.

```
string s = @"//table[@data-account='test']//span[contains(.,'FB')]";
string[] stringarray = s.Split(new string[1] {@"//"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine("//" + stringarray[0]);
```

Output will be;

```
//table[@data-account='test']
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/OO1zeQ).

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            Regex.Match("//table[@data-account='test']//span[contains(.,'FB')]", "^([^]]+])").Groups[1].Value);
    }
}
```